# can anyone tell me, number of hit required and time period in which hits to be done, for staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency, enter True to disable the behavior that a static file is compressed only if it is hit a certain number of times within a time period. can anyone tell me, number of hit required and time period in which hits to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **system.webServer/serverRuntime** section for the default values:

`frequentHitThreshold` for number of times

`frequentHitTimePeriod` for the period

defaults to 2 hits in 10 seconds.

But rather than fiddling with these you may want to just use the staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency parameter if you want to disable this completely. This way static content will be compressed and cached from the outset and won't switch between static and dynamic compression. This will also mean that the ETag in the response doesn't vary.